# Can I just use Mac Grapher to copy LaTeX Expression on this site?

Tags: mac

There is a APP on Mac called Grapher,and when you type a mathematics equation,you can use "copy LaTeX Expression",my question is can the expression I used work on this site?I mean just copy and paste.Or more specific ,can it run on Mathematics Exchange?

Example,I type x^2 in Grapher,and use"copy LaTeX Expression",I get "y=x^{2}",can I just copy "y=x^{2}"into this site,and it will show beautiful equation?

Comment: It's pretty off topic here. If you have questions regarding this site, ask on [meta].

Comment: @ Stefan Kottwitz♦,Sir,with all due respect,I still can't figure it out how to type equation in Mathematics StackExchange,and they require 10 reputation to ask meta question.I had tried my best to understand the F&Q,maybe I am just a little too stupid...

Comment: Take a look at [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths), where this has been answered in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but on some sites on the network MathJax is installed so you can place TeX commands between `$y=x^{2}$` and it will render as mathematics. That includes https://math.stackexchange.com/

MathJax is not enabled on this site, if you wish to show the rendered TeX output you need to upload an image.

Comment: Thank you,good sir!I just want to figure it out how to type equation on Math StackExchange,I still can't understand the F&Q there.I thought I could just use Math Grapher to do that.

Comment: You should be able to ask in the meta for the math site I'm afraid the question is way off topic here and will likely be closed. But it should just work if you surround the math with $ as far as I can see

Comment: You sir are an angel.I can't thank you enough